# Sitecore comparing two items

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, sitecore

Lets say I have two items:

- Cat
- Dog

Is there anyway of comparing them easily to see difference between the two? I know I can get PublishedItemComparer which compares -Cat to -CatDB(being the published item in the database). Also Sitecore version ribbon allows you to compare revisions of the content item in sitecore.

I guess the released comparison tools just arn't enough for my needs. Let me know if there is a solution currently out there if not I may have to look into creating one :D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take advantage of the item serialization here.

Here's what you should do:

- open Content Editor and activate the Developer tab in the ribbon. For this, right click the  ribbon and choose 'Developer' - it should be the only inactive tab there
- select an item (one of those two you'd like to compare) in content tree, switch to the Developer tab and press 'Serialize item' button. This operation will create a TXT representation of this item under `/data/serialization` by default
- select the other item and repeat the previous step

Now, when you have TXT representation of each items, you can use usual comparing tools, like WinMerge, to do the actual comparison.

Comment: I noticed in web.config you set the default location of serialization folder, even though it is set to /data/serialization when I trying creating the text no text is created. Will look into this some more.

Comment: It might be permissions. Check that the AppPool identity has read/write to the folder in question. Also, check the Sitecore logs for possible errors

Comment: bizarre AppPool being used is DefaultAppPool its associated identity user has read/write access to the folders... sigh will look into it further.

Comment: I will give it till the end of the week, this is a nice working answer just want to see if there are alternatives.